# unable to add NSURL object to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I am just learning objective-c but can't figure out whats wrong with my code

Code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDic = [NSDictionary dictionary];

[myDic setObject:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"] forKey:@"Apple"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you're declaring `NSMutableDictionary` you're creating immutable `NSDictionary` object.

The correct declaration and initialization of `myDic` would be

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```